# Conexão entre dois containers docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Criei 3 containers para iniciar a minha aplicação, são eles:

```
version: "2"

services:

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: rgsistema-mysql
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - .:/application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rgsistema
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=rgsistema
    - MYSQL_USER=rgsistema
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rgsistema
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

webserver:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: rgsistema-webserver
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - ./rgsistema/:/application
    - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
    - "8888:80"
  links:
    - mysql

php-fpm:
  build: phpdocker/php-fpm
  container_name: rgsistema-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - ./rgsistema/:/application
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
  links:
    - mysql
```

Minha aplicação esta rodando OK, porem não consegue conectar ao banco de dados, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Estou usando o Laravel 5, meu .env esta da seguinte maneira:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rgsistema
DB_USERNAME=rgsistema
DB_PASSWORD=rgsistema
```

Ao testar a conexão entre eles, tenho a seguinte resposta:

docker container exec -it rgsistema-webserver ping rgsistema-php-fpm = ok

docker container exec -it rgsistema-webserver ping rgsistema-mysql = ok

docker container exec -it rgsistema-php-fpm ping rgsistema-mysql = erro

docker container exec -it rgsistema-php-fpm ping rgsistema-webserver = erro

Erro apresentado:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

docker ps

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já verificou a rede entre eles? e quais sãos IP de cada container?

Comment: você pode usar o comando: docker ps

Comment: coloquei uma imagem demonstrando

Comment: você tem o portainer instalado? Por ele você conseguiria criar uma rede e incluir os contatiner que você deseja. [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/installation/)

Comment: consegui resolver, oque tive que fazer é no meu arquivo .env, em vez de deixar o DB_HOST como 127.0.0.1, tem que ser mysql.

Comment: cuidado ao colocar o password do seu banco de dados em locais públicos como o StackOverflow, eu entendo que seu código está rodando de um servidor de aplicação local, onde creio eu que não haja forma de acessar remotamente, mas se você por ventura postar por exemplo o usuário e senha do seu banco de PRD por exemplo, alguém mal intencionado pode acessar seus dados, caso seu banco não possua mecanismos de proteção como restrição de acesso por IP de rede por exemplo. Evite sempre postar informações confidenciais no StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar a configuração de [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links), você está especificando um `service:alias` que permite que o referido container fique acessível utilizando o nome do serviço e/ou alias definido.

Por exemplo. Ao definir:

```
php-fpm:
  links:
   - mysql
   - mysql:database
```

Seu container `php-fpm` pode se comunicar com seu banco de dados tanto pelo hostname `mysql` quanto por `database`.

No seu caso, você deve trocar sua `DB_HOST`, pois `127.0.0.1` significa que o `php-fpm` está tentando se conectar em si mesmo, e não no container do banco de dados. **O correto é ficar assim:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
...
```

---

Importante ressaltar que a configuração de `links` está depreciada, e pode ser removida do Docker a qualquer momento.

Dê uma olhada na configuração de [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) para entender maneira recomendada de configurar a rede dos containers.

Answer (score 0):

Olá :)
Tive o mesmo problema, resolvi alterando o DB_HOST pelo ip do host.docker.internal que está no ficheiro hosts.